# get session_id value to use it in a variable in jquery and post to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have got my `$session_id = $_SESSION['users_id'] = 201780001` here.

I am trying to display my data from database to my datatable based on the session:

```
var table = $('#table-clinic'),
    datatable,
    tr,
    data,
    sessionID = '<?php echo $session_id; ?>';


var datatable = table.DataTable({
    ajax:{
        type: 'POST',
        url:'../ajax/viewclinic.php',
        data: {
          'clinic_usersid': sessionID 
        },
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    column:[
        {
            "data": null,
            mRender: function (data) {
                 return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="update-row" style="background: none;border: 0px;padding: 0px;"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:16px;"></i></button></a>'+" "+
                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete-row" style="background: none;border: 0px;padding: 0px;"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size:16px;"></i></button></a>'; 
              }
        },
        {"data": "clinic_id"},
        {"data": "clinic_usersid"},
        {"data": "clinic_name"},
        {"data": "clinic_address"},
        {"data": "clinic_tel"},
        {"data": "clinic_schedule"},
        {"data": "clinic_time"},
        {"data": "clinic_type"} 
    ]

});
```

Here is my jquery code that displays my data from my database.

**viewclinic.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['clinic_usersid'])) {
     $id = $_POST['clinic_usersid'];
     $data = $clinic->clinicList($id);

     echo json_encode($data);
}
```

This is the one called by ajax

```
public function clinicList($clinic_id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_clinic WHERE clinic_usersid = '$clinic_id'";
        $result = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data;
    }
```

This is my query.. So, based on my session id the data will be display if my `clinic_usersid` equals to `$session_id`, but nothing is being displayed and nothing is being posted to my ajax.

Comment: As you are using `PDO:prepare()`, why in the world are you directly injecting the variable/value into your query, and not using a placeholder? That is like buying a safe but never locking it.

Comment: Debugging 101 - working backward. Does  `SELECT * FROM tbl_clinic WHERE clinic_usersid = 201780001` return anything? Does `$data = $clinic->clinicList(201780001);` return anything? Does `data: {  'clinic_usersid': 201780001 },` return anything? Have you even looking at your browser developer tools/console to see if your ajax was firing? Or what the returned data looked like?

Comment: i check the console but nothing is being returned

Comment: does the console show that the ajax fired/executed?

Comment: none... i tried to echo inside my 
`if (isset($_POST['clinic_usersid'])) {
   echo "asd";
}`

but even echo is not showing.. feels like 
`data: {
          'clinic_usersid': sessionID 
        },`
does not pushing the session id...

Comment: so try changing `viewclinic.php` to something like `echo json_encode($_POST);` to see what is being sent.

Comment: i tried changing it to `echo json_encode($_POST) but nothing shows on my console and it says that no data available on my datatable... but there is a data which my `session_id = clinic_userid` and i also tried your debugging with `echo json_encode($data)` and the error is like this `Datatables warning:table id=table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0.

Comment: sessionID = '<?php echo $session_id; ?>'; doesn't work. Try to run it with sessionID = 201780001 to check the results. You cannot parse PHP code in jQuery.

Comment: it works now.. i fortgot to put "s" on column... it should be columns not column... sorry guys... thanks for the effort btw.